# Use a cron job to store large API calls locally

Tags: php, api, cron

I've been using an API for a project lately and when a user searches his/her name in the box, it brings up 5 opponents that they are facing.  I call an API five seperate times to retreive data that is then displayed on the next page for each of the 5 opponents.  However, this causes the page to take a really long time to load (~30 seconds sometimes).  I saw somewhere that cron jobs can be used to store data locally so that API calls don't need to happen on the page load.  Now my question is, is there a way to pull all the user's data through the API via cron job and store it locally for later use?  The only issue is that this API is for League of Legends which has over 30 million users.  I cannot fathom how long it would take to aquire all of those user's data and refresh it every so often.  So is there a way to use cron jobs or another method of sorts to have my page not take half a minute to load?  These are the API calls that are holding up the site:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($enemyTeamIds as $enemyTeamId) {
$url="APILINK";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('auth: key'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$json_array=curl_exec($ch);
$enemyIds[$i] = json_decode($json_array, true);
$i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to download all 30 million users, you just need to download the data for YOUR users, right? You don't have 30 million users, do you?

Comment: If its calling up the next 5 opponents they are facing ... if you ran the cron job earlier in the day wouldn't that information be outdated?

Comment: @Barmar I don't have any actual users.  Anyone can go on the website who plays League of Legends and search for their name if they are in a game.  So essentially I would need to ideally store all 30 million users, but I have no idea how to do that in an efficient manner

Comment: @user1895377 no no no and no... when you query a user from your site to consume the API you then store that user.

Comment: Where are you getting the array `$enemyTeamIds`?

Comment: Check whether they have an API that allows you to supply a list of IDs, so you can do one call instead of 5.

Comment: @LozCherone so you're saying to save them locally as people search them to that next time that name comes up it can use the local copy?

Comment: @user1895377, wouldn't that make more sense than killing someone else' server constantly downloading data you may never use?

Comment: @developerwjk yeah that does make sense. I guess it would just take a while for it to start getting faster because there would be no users locally stored at first.

Answer (score 0):

When you query a user/team within your loop first check your db, and only query the API if the team not found, then store that result, for keeping the team updated you could put a timestamp in the row as to when the team was last updated. Initially your do lots of API calls then over time your only need to update the users/teams that are associated with your site.

Heres some pseudo code:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach($enemyTeamIds as $enemyTeamId){

    //query your own db for enemyTeamId
    $result = get_from_db($enemyTeamId);

    //already have team
    if(!empty($result)){

        //if result older then 1 day - update
        if($result['timestamp'] < (time() - 86400)){
            //re query API for updates
            $result = query_api_team($enemyTeamId);
            //update result in your db
            update_in_db($enemyTeamId, $result);
        }
    }
    //dont have team query API
    else{

        //query API
        $result = query_api_team($enemyTeamId);
        //store result in your db
        put_in_db($enemyTeamId, $result);
    }

    $enemyIds[$i] = json_decode($result, true);
    $i++;
}

function query_api_team($enemyTeamId){
    //query API
    $ch = curl_init();
    ...
    ...
    return $json_array;
}
?>
```

Though you could use cron to run a script periodically do some housekeeping to update, remove old teams ect.

Comment: So if I were to do that, how would a cron job search just the ID's in the table for updates? Also, as the table of users gets larger and larger, won't the cron job start running hundreds of thousands of API calls to check for updates?

Comment: The cron script would query the database based on **timestamp** and return the ids, the cron job if run say every day would never return hundreds of thousands of ids to update only *max* a days worth of ids (if no user visited your site for a day). Adding coumns for team activity you could also put low accessed teams in a low priority batch update and only update them once a week. You dont do things all at once when it comes to big numbers/rows.

Comment: @user1895377 made a small change to the pseudo code, which would update the team once a day, hoping you understand. good luck